# Date comparison returns "NaN"

Tags: jquery

I stuck with one issue, here I would like to compare two dates, but it is giving "NaN". I tried with below code,

```
<input type="text" value="10-10-2015 20:00:08" id="startDateVal"/>
<input type="text" value="11-10-2015 23:00:10" id="lpoendDate_1"/>
```

---

```
var startDateVal = $("#lpoendDate_1").val().replace(/-/gi,'/');

var endDateVal = $("#lpostartDate_1").val().replace(/-/gi,'/');

var testresult = (new Date(endDateVal) - new Date(startDateVal) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

alert(testresult);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9y1337e/8/)

Comment: In your HTML, the `id` of the first input is wrong, should be `id="lpostartDate_1"` (according to your JS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

your start date is `#startDateVal`

```
<input type="text" value="10-10-2015 20:00:08" id="startDateVal"/>
<input type="text" value="11-10-2015 23:00:10" id="lpoendDate_1"/>
```

so:-

```
var startDateVal = $("#startDateVal").val()
var  endDateVal= $("#lpoendDate_1").val()

var testresult = (new Date(endDateVal) - new Date(startDateVal) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

console.log(testresult); // 748.0005555555556
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDateVal = $("#startDateVal").val().split(/-|\s|:/);
var  endDateVal= $("#lpoendDate_1").val().split(/-|\s|:/);
var testresult = ((new Date(endDateVal[2],endDateVal[1],endDateVal[0],endDateVal[3],endDateVal[4],endDateVal[5])) -(new Date(startDateVal[2],startDateVal[1],startDateVal[0],startDateVal[3],startDateVal[4],startDateVal[5])) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

alert(testresult);
```

Your date is in dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss format. Hence your new Date is not working.
you need to first convert it into valid date.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var endDateVal = $("#lpoendDate_1").val().split(/-|\s|:/);
    endDateVal = new Date(endDateVal[2], endDateVal[1], endDateVal[0], endDateVal[3], endDateVal[4], endDateVal[5]);
    var startDateVal = $("#startDateVal").val().split(/-|\s|:/);
    startDateVal = new Date(startDateVal[2], startDateVal[1], startDateVal[0], startDateVal[3], startDateVal[4], startDateVal[5]);
    var testresult = (endDateVal - startDateVal) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

    alert(testresult);
```